# Access useContext from a child function outside parent function?

Tags: react-native

I have a functional component with Context API set up as such

```
import AppContext from "./Context";

const item=()=>{
  const { Verified } = useContext(AppContext)

  return (<>...</>)
}

export default function SubPage() {

 return (
    ...
    <item/>
 )
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, It gives the error:

> Error: Invalid hook call.

I can't figure out which rule of hook I've broken, could someone please help out?

Comment: Have you wrapped the parent component with the context `Provider`?

Comment: @amerw yes The context API works, I've tested it in other components

Comment: too less code to realize the problem, can you put more log, or more code?